# Viewing file properties instead of file in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, libraries, document

I have a document library on SharePoint online with lots of columns for metadata. These columns won't fit in a single view on screen, so I want the users to first view the properties of the file before downloading them.

Is there a way to change the behavior of the SharePoint library ensure that the user views the file properties first when they click on the filename?

PS: I understand I could have used lists, but after loading about 10000 documents, I have decided to use it as a last resort. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Custom the LinkFilename field by [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

Sample code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var CustomWidthCtx = {};

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    function init() {

        CustomWidthCtx.Templates = {};

        CustomWidthCtx.Templates.Fields = {            
            'LinkFilename': {
                'View': customDisplay
            }
        };

        // Register the custom template
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(CustomWidthCtx);
    }

    /**
     * Rendering template
     */
    function customDisplay(ctx) {
        var currentVal = '';
        //from the context get the current item and it's value 
        if (ctx != null && ctx.CurrentItem != null)
            currentVal = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

        var el = "<div class='ms-vb  itx' id='" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "' app='' ctxname='ctx37'><a title='" + ctx.CurrentItem._ShortcutUrl + "' class='ms-listlink ms-draggable' aria-label='Shortcut file' onfocus='OnLink(this)' href='/Doc4/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "' target='_blank' DragId='17'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + "</a></div>";

        // Render the HTML5 file input in place of the OOTB
        return el;
    }

    // Run our intiialization
    init();

})();
```